# Did a git reset --hard, but still conflicts at git pull

Tags: git, github

I did a git reset --hard

- Then I tried `git pull` , but gives merge conflicts
- I also tried `git pull --rebase`, still gives merge conflicts

I do not understand, that upon `git reset --hard` there should be no local changes(Verified through *git status* also)

**Then why the conflict arising ?**

As per my understanding, conflict occurs, when there are changes at the same line. But, this scenario should not occur, as I have done a *git reset --hard*

[image]

Comment: Just do what the hints state :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a flaw in your reasoning here:

> [after] `git reset --hard` there should be no local changes (Verified through *git status* also)

The fact that `git status` says:

```
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

does not mean that there are no "local changes".  It means there are no *uncommitted* changes.

#### About `git pull`: I recommend not using it

Both kinds of `git pull`—with or without `--rebase`—means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*.  The version with `--rebase` means *use `git rebase` as the second command, instead of the default command*.  The default command depends on how you've configured your `git pull`; if you have not configured it at all, the default default is `git merge`.

The `git pull` command is meant to be convenient.  After your `git fetch`, you will usually want to incorporate fetched commits, and to do so, you will generally use either `git merge` or `git rebase`.  The `git pull` command combines both of the two commits—fetch-then-merge, or fetch-then-rebase—into one more-convenient command.  The problems with combining them include:

- This means you can't insert any commands *between* the two commands.  You can't look to see what `git fetch` fetched, before you try to incorporate these.  That's a bit like opening your door when the doorbell rings, then jumping into a delivered box that you expect to contain pillows.  What if they delivered a box of snakes instead?  Maybe it would be wise to *look* before you leap.<sup>1</sup>
- If something goes wrong (as it did here), you may not know what to do to recover.
- The pull command's syntax is weird: it's different from *all* other Git commands, in ways that are tricky to explain.  It's at least sort of similar to `git push`, but thinking along these lines misleads, because pull and push do not go together that well: the opposite of push is really fetch, not pull.

---

<sup>1</sup>[There are valid objections to this philosophy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11360858/1256452).  You *can* undo things, once you know how.  If you're well versed in all things Git, feel free to pick whichever method works best for you.  I use a mix of pull or fetch-then-command, myself.

---

#### So why *are* conflicts arising?

Your image shows that you're already in the partially-merged, merge-or-rebase-still-ongoing-but-hasn't-completed phase of a `git pull` that ran one of those second commands.  When you *are* in this state, many Git commands cannot proceed.  That includes `git pull`.

To get out of this state, you must either finish the in-progress command—whether that's `git merge` or `git rebase`—or stop it entirely.  To stop it entirely, you can use:

- `git merge --abort`, if it is a merge that is in progress; or
- `git rebase --abort`, if it is a rebase that is in progress; or
- `git reset --hard`, regardless of which of these two is in progress.

All three commands put you back to where you were before you started, with some caveats.  (I won't go into details as I am short on time.)

We can't say for certain *exactly* why you are getting conflicts—not without access to your repository, anyway.  But a crucial thing to know about Git is that Git is all about *commits*.  Commits are the unit of storage at which you work in Git.  Commits are mostly permanent—they live as long as you can *find* them—and are completely, totally, 100% read-only.  You can never change *anything* about any commit.

Each commit has a unique hash ID.  This hash ID is the same in *every* Git everywhere.  That makes it easy for your Git and any other Git to exchange commits.  They just check: do they both have that hash ID?  If so, they both have *that* commit.  If not, the one that has the commit can give it to the other Git.

Each commit stores a complete snapshot of all of your files.  The files inside a commit are frozen: no part of any commit can ever be changed, including the stored files.  The files themselves are stored in a special, read-only, compressed and Git-only format, in which Git does de-duplication too, so the fact that *every* commit has *every* file doesn't cost anything: if a thousand commits have a thousand copies of some file, but all those copies are the same, there's really only *one* copy after all.

Any *branch name*, or any other name such as a tag name or a remote-tracking name, just stores the raw hash ID of *one commit*.  It's the commits themselves that form into structures.  See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  The *branch names* identify the *last* commit in some series of commits.

When you run `git fetch`, you have your Git call up some other Git and *get* any new commits from them.  Your Git and their Git look over the various hash IDs and figure out which commits they have, and you don't.  Your Get gets their commits and now you share commits—but you can have commits *they* don't.

When you run `git merge`, you pick out some commit of theirs—usually by a remote-tracking name like `origin/master` or `origin/dev`, and often you have your own `master` or dev`, maybe for a different *last* commit—and tell your Git: *combine what I have now, with what's in that commit*.  If you have commits that they don't, and they have commits that you didn't before, this *combining* can result in merge conflicts.

When you run `git rebase`, you pick out some commit of theirs and tell your Git: *copy commits I have now, that they don't, so that they build on their last commit*.  This copying process can result in merge conflicts.

If you have commits that they didn't, and you did not *expect* to have commits that they didn't, you should figure out why that's the case.  But that's almost certainly the case here.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation!

Comment: I used ```git rebase --skip``` to get things moving forward

Comment: Be careful with `--skip`: this means *although I'm copying commits, I've decided I would like to leave this one one of the copied ones*. In other words, you've decided that some of your commits are no good and you'd like to remove them from the "replayed" ones.

Comment: This *may* be what you want! Just be sure that it is. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`git reset --hard` syncs what you have in your workspace to what's in your local repository (to whatever commit id you happen to be pointing to).   `git pull` pulls commits from the remote into your local repository, and then tries to merge your workspace to the latest commit --  where it detects a conflict.

What's likely happening is that you submitted a commit to your local repository, and it conflicts with something being pulled down.   If you did not commit anything, it's also possible that someone did a rebase on the remote repository, or your remote branch has changed, and what you have conflicts with what's being pulled down.   Check the logs of what you have in your local branch vs what's in the remote and it should shed some light on this.

Comment: So, in my case, I forgot to point to the remote/branch when resetting. I had to run `git reset --hard origin/master` before being able to pull cleanly from that remote.

Answer (score 0):

It could still happen if you have ignored (by you) files that are coming from the PR. Is that the case?